# WSL alias with doskey not working on Windows

Tags: docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux, doskey

For some commercial reasons, I am no longer allowed to use [Docker Desktop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docker_(software)#Adoption) on my company's computer. However, I installed the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) for using Docker commands directly within the WSL, and it's working fine when typing "wsl" on my cmd and then "docker":

[image]

It works also when typing the full command using "wsl" prefix inside my cmd, like this :

```
wsl /snap/bin/docker
```

So I tried to create an alias using [DOSKEY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOSKEY), like this:

```
doskey docker=wsl /snap/bin/docker
```

For a more convenient use.

But when I try to execute Docker commands with my new alias, it only shows me the manual and nothing else, no matter the argument:

```
C:\Users\myUser>docker image ls

Usage:  docker [OPTIONS] COMMAND

A self-sufficient runtime for containers

Options: <All the options and commands available in the manual when typing "docker">
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: could you also please edit your answer post to make it more clear how it answers the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was simple, doskey does not accept arguments ^^ So I created a .cmd script called "docker.cmd" written like this :

```
@echo off
wsl /snap/bin/docker %*
```

And then I put this file in my System32 folder (it works with any other folder in the PATH environment variable, I put it in System32 just for the test). The %* allows me to put arguments, and now my command works fine. Not really an alias, but it's doing the job.

But this script raises another problem, detailed in this question : [WSL Docker with Windows : Docker Daemon not started when typing commands with custom script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77411443/wsl-docker-with-windows-docker-daemon-not-started-when-typing-commands-with-cu)