# WSL Docker with Windows : Docker Daemon not started when typing commands with custom script

Tags: docker

This question follow this one :
[WSL alias with doskey not working on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77395078/wsl-alias-with-doskey-not-working-on-windows)

So I created a .cmd script to use Docker from my WSL within a CMD prompt and the command works fine, but not always. When I first try to use my command, I have this result :

```
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

I noticed dy docker service wasn't started with my first command, so I started it using snap, like this :

```
sudo snap start docker
```

And then my Docker commands are working with my custom script. But if I close my command prompt and wait a few minues and then I retry with a new command prompt, the error shows again.

Is there a way to make the Docker Daemon "persistent", so I can use my Docker command at any time without having to start the Docker Daemon every time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found where was my problem. I used snap to install Docker on my Ubuntu, with this command :

```
sudo snap install docker
```

But snap doesn't create the **/var/run/docker.sock** file, and that's why my script wasn't working as I expected. But in Docker documentation there's a way to add docker to your local apt repository :

https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/

So I uninstalled and reinstalled a clean instance of Ubuntu 22.04, I followed these steps to install properly Docker on this instance, and then I edited my **docker.cmd** script like this :

```
@echo off
wsl -d Ubuntu-22.04 docker %*
```

And now my commands are working fine without any problem from my Docker Daemon.